# How can I convert db datetime to datetime in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am getting error while trying to get datetime column from SQL Server by using Entity Framework and Linq expression.

The error is "***: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.''***"

```
List<string> name = new List<string>();
List<DateTime> _startDate = new List<DateTime>();
List<DateTime> _endDate = new List<DateTime>();

var data = _appDbContext.Student
.Where(x =>
name.Contains(x.Name)
 && _startDate.Contains(x.StartDate)
 && _endDate.Contains(x.EndDate))
.ToList();
```

**My Student Class**

```
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried using DateTime.Parse(s.StartDate) but this is not working,
tried using (DateTime)(Object)(s.StartDate) but still not working.

**Error on:**

```
_endDate.Contains(x.EndDate))
_startDate.Contains(x.StartDate)
```

Comment: Why are you using `Contains()` in your `Where()`? Also, what line is the error in?

Comment: @AmalK I have list of items which needs to be searched which includes list of name, list of start and end date. The error is in _startDate.Contains(x.StartDate)

Comment: What are the types of `icp`, `_startDate` and `_endDate`?

Comment: Just tried the same in my ef-core db and it worked without any problems. Maybe doesn't your db schema match your ef core entities? What is the underlying datatype of your date columns in your database? Is it really a datetime type or just a string?

Comment: Chances are your database and code are using different date formatting that the EF expressing to do the 'IN' clause for `Contains` is formatting something in DD/MM/YYYY where the server is using MM/DD/YYYY. Check your application server's date format and your database server's date format to ensure they match.  Your example is a very odd type of search to perform.

Comment: @Oliver I am using SQL Server, and over there the datatype of the column is datetime.